# Select only cells with data but skip the first cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this script.

```
Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
For Each xCell In Selection
xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
Next xCell
```

I want to only select the cells in column E that have data, but the amount of cells that have data varies, and I don't want to select E1 because it has a header. This code changes the foreign text in column E to numbers that I can actually use the sum function to add up. The way it is written now it puts a 0 in all of the cells in the column infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Application.Max(2, Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

With Range("E2:E" & lastrow)
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**UPD:**

if it doesn't help, try this:

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Application.Max(2, Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

For i = 2 To lastrow
    With Range("E" & i)
        .Value = CDec(.Value)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Won't taking the min of 2 and the last row always return 2? (unless last row is 1) Did you mean max?

Comment: This isn't the full macro I am running, but it is the only part I can't figure out. I need to be able to put it into the rest of the macro not be it's own macro.

Comment: no problem, just select all inside `Sub` statement and paste to your macro.

Comment: I've rewrote your code to avoid `Select` statements, because it's very bad way of programming. But my code and your doing the same things

Comment: The number format thing does not work. I have no idea why, but with the foreign text the way it is the only way to convert it to an actual number in excel is to use the code I used in the top. I have no idea why it works but it does. If I sum after running your code I still got 0 as the answer.

Comment: I get an error, the .Value = Cdec(.Value) line gives Run Time Error '13' Type mismatch in the debugging

Comment: what kind of data do you have in your E column?

Comment: The E column is numbers that have manually been copied from a webpage so they are treated as text even if you format the cells as numbers because they are foreign data. The original code I used is the only code I have found that works on them, but it makes the data after the column is completed 0s all the way to like row 60000 or something so it increases the file size significantly.